# xamarin.forms - Change the view of a button by a gridlayout

Tags: button, grid-layout, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to replace the view/layout of a button by a gridlayout to change its look and of course keeping behaviours?
The gridlayout would be composed of a label and images.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can but you won't keep all behaviours like click.
What you can do is add a Tap event to the grid.

```cs
var grid = new Grid();
var tapGestureRecognizer= new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => {
    // handle the tap
};
grid.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
```